# How to change the default "Portrait Orientation" to Landscape in Android Print Framework?

Tags: android, android-print-framework

Is there a way to change default portrait preview to landscape in print framework?

I have tried below -

```
PrintAttributes attrib = new PrintAttributes.Builder()
.setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.NA_LETTER.asLandscape())
.setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS)
. build();
```

and also tried below -

```
PrintAttributes attrib = new PrintAttributes.Builder()
.setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.UNKNOWN_LANDSCAPE)
.setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS)
. build();
```

I've noticed that it doesn't change the page orientation to **Landscape**

[image: print settings]

In above print setting dialog if I do change the orientation to landscape then and only then the print preview page changes orientation to **Landscape**. Can this be done programmatically? I want default preview in Landscape.

Comment: hi any solution for this?

Comment: @Edgar: I didn't found any solution, so I chose default portrait layout.

Comment: Hi, Any solution. I am getting this issue in few devices Nexus including

Answer (score 7):

I used below Code:

```
PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
    String jobName = this.getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";

    PrintAttributes attrib = new PrintAttributes.Builder()
            .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.UNKNOWN_LANDSCAPE)
            . build();

    printManager.print(jobName, pda, attrib);
```

My Result:

[image]

Comment: when apply this, it makes app crash with this exception: **IllegalArgumentException: page width must be positive**

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone find it useful, it’s possible to set the orientation from MediaSize object using `asPortrait()` or `asLandscape()`.

Example:

```
PrintAttributes attributes = new PrintAttributes.Builder().
setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4.asLandscape()).build();
```

If someone want to set this dynamically based on a PDF file dimension, it’s is also possible to use PdfRenderer to render a page and get　the PDF dimensions:

```
try {
        ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(pdfFile, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
        PdfRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(fileDescriptor);
        PdfRenderer.Page p= pdfRenderer.openPage(1);
        if(p.getHeight()>=p.getWidth())
            printAttrbutesBuilder.setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4.asPortrait());
        else
            printAttrbutesBuilder.setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4.asLandscape());
    }catch (Exception e){
        printAttrbutesBuilder.setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4);
    }
```